# Delete Job is taking more than 16 hours to complete

Tags: sql-server

I have a delete job in SQL Server 2008 and it is taking 16+ hours to complete.

Here is the content of the job. Is there any possibility to tune it?

```
BEGIN    
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from    
 SET NOCOUNT ON;    
--Modified as per the new request as  a part of project XIRI P2 Quick Hit Solution--banu    
    DECLARE @DELETECOUNT int    
    DECLARE @DELETEATATIME int    
   -- DECLARE @TBLCOUNT int    
    --DECLARE @MAXRETENTION int    
   -- DECLARE @ROWSDELETEDCOUNT int    
 DECLARE @CutOffDate datetime    
 DECLARE @HourRetained smallint    
 set @HourRetained = 24    
begin Try    
    --SELECT @TBLCOUNT = COUNT(*) FROM tblcalldatastore WITH (READPAST) WHERE IsTestCase=0    

    --SET @MAXRETENTION = 100000    

 set @CutOffDate = getutcdate()    

    select  @DELETECOUNT = count(*) 
      from [tblcalldatastore]    
     where  istestcase=0    
       and datediff(hour,receiveddate,@CutOffDate)>@HourRetained    

    SET @DELETEATATIME = 2000    

  --  CREATE TABLE #Temptbl    
  --    (    

  --      CollTag varchar(255),    
  --ReceivedDate datetime    
  --    )    


--    INSERT INTO #Temptbl    
--    SELECT TOP (@DELETECOUNT) CollTag, ReceivedDate 
        FROM tblcalldatastore WITH (NOLOCK) 
       WHERE IsTestCase=0 and datediff(hour,receiveddate,getutcdate())>@HourRetained    
--ORDER BY ReceivedDate ASC    

    --SELECT @ROWSDELETEDCOUNT = count(*) from #Temptbl    

    WHILE @DELETECOUNT > 0    

    BEGIN    

   DELETE TOP(@DELETEATATIME) FROM tblcalldatastore WITH (ROWLOCK)  WHERE IsTestCase=0 and datediff(hour,receiveddate,@CutOffDate)>@HourRetained     

      --DELETE FROM tblcalldatastore WITH (ROWLOCK)    
      --WHERE CollTag IN    
      --(SELECT TOP (@DELETEATATIME) CollTag FROM #TempTbl ORDER BY ReceivedDate ASC)    

      SET @DELETECOUNT = @DELETECOUNT - @DELETEATATIME     

   --DELETE FROM #TempTbl     
   --WHERE CollTag in (SELECT TOP (@DELETEATATIME) CollTag FROM #TempTbl ORDER BY ReceivedDate ASC)    
      --SET @DELETEATATIME = @DELETEATATIME + 2000    

    END    

    --DROP TABLE #Temptbl    

    --PRINT @ROWSDELETEDCOUNT    


end try    


BEGIN CATCH    

SELECT 'FAILED - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage    

END CATCH    

END
```

Indexes on the table

```
  USE [GRSQWS]

/****** Object:  Index [idx_CollTag_IsTestCase]    Script Date:      07/03/2019 07:12:37 ******/
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_CollTag_IsTestCase] ON [dbo].                                          [tblCallDataStore] 
    (
    [CollTag] ASC,
    [IsTestCase] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,      SORT_IN_TEMPDB    

    = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF,   ONLINE = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]  
GO

    /****** Object:  Index [idx_CollTag_SerialNo_Model]    Script Date:     07/03/2019 07:12:37 ******/
     CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_CollTag_SerialNo_Model] ON    [dbo].[tblCallDataStore] 
    (
    [CollTag] ASC
    )
    INCLUDE ( [SerialNumber],
    [MachineModel],
    [ReceivedDate],
    [IsTestCase],
    [DeviceData]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,     SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE =  OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [idx_IsTestCase_ReceivedDate]    Script Date: 07/03/2019 07:12:37 ******/
     CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_IsTestCase_ReceivedDate] ON [dbo].[tblCallDataStore] 
(
    [IsTestCase] ASC
)
    INCLUDE ( [ReceivedDate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF,   STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_tblcalldatastore_receiveddate]    Script Date: 07/03/2019 07:12:37 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblcalldatastore_receiveddate] ON [dbo].[tblCallDataStore] 
(
    [ReceivedDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_tblCallDataStore_1]    Script Date: 07/03/2019 07:12:37 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCallDataStore] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCallDataStore_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CollTag] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  enter code here= ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: `datediff(hour,receiveddate,@CutOffDate)>@HourRetained` isn't going to be SARGable, so that'll be a likely candidate as a performance killer. Also, why only 2000 rows at a time? SQL Server, can easily handle far more rows than that at once.

Comment: Thanks Sir, Could you please suggest your code if I need to change this one?

Comment: A suggestion for a sargable expression: `dateadd(hour,@HourRetained*-1,@CutOffDate)<=receiveddate`

Comment: Thanks Dan, Should I increase the number of rows selected as well?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table `tblcalldatastore` as well? If yes, what are they, can you put their DDL in your question? If not, if if none of them are appropriate for the query,then that will be another contributing factor.

Comment: Sure, i am going to add Indexes in my question as well, I just need a minute

Comment: I just noticed as well you do a `COUNT` of how many rows to delete, and then loop on that. It might be better to check the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` after the delete and see if it's lower than the value of `@DELETEATATIME`. if it is, you know that no more rows are available to delete. That'll reduce the number of scans/seeks on the table by 1 (which if it's a big table could be a decent time saver).

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I have updated the indexes in my question.

Comment: @Andy, yes, I would increase the rows per batch like Larnu suggested. The optimal number depends on how much concurrency you need, log size, memory, execution plan. Maybe a few hundred thousand for starters.

Comment: Thaks Dan, I would increase the rows count per batch and will see the change in job runtime.